# Generate python code for execution (auto correct """)

Tags: python, string, exec, code-generation

I write a python code generator
as an input it has a source code: `source`
Part of the output I need to generate is `execute(source_code)`
When `source_code` is a string representing `source` .
If I write `"execute({0})".format(source)` for input source = "import sys"
i'll get `execute(import sys)`.
So I tried : `execute(\"\"\"{0}\"\"\")format(source)`. Is it ok? I tried to test it...Sometimes it is ok....The problem occurs when inside the source there are`"""`
For example:

```
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML("""
<script>
console.log("hello");
</script>
<b>HTML</b>
""")
```

my code turns to be

```
execute("""from IPython.display import HTML
HTML("""
<script>
console.log("hello");
</script>
<b>HTML</b>
""")""")
```

**UPD:**
Changing the code to

```
execute('''{0}''').format(source)
```

doesn`t solve the problem, the issue will be encountered with :

```
def tojson(data):
    '''Shorten the code to respond a little bit.'''
    print(json.dumps(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using single triple quotes should help:

```
execute('''from IPython.display import HTML
HTML("""
<script>
console.log("hello");
</script>
<b>HTML</b>
""")''')
```

Running in a Notebook, you need to use `eval()` to actually display the **HTML**:

```
exec('''from IPython.display import HTML''')
eval('''HTML("""
<script>
console.log("hello");
</script>
<b>HTML</b>
""")''')
```

In your case probably:

```
execute('''{0}''').format(source)
```

Works also if there are `'''` inside the string:

```
source = """
def add(a, b):
    '''Add'''
    return a + b

print(add(1, 2))
"""

exec('''{0}'''.format(source))
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: changing to execute('''{0}''')format(source) indeed works! thanks! but what happens if inside source there is '''? I will encounter the same issue?